# given SuperString possible using any combination of given substrings or not

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose we have  input substrings-- "john" "mathew" "carl"
we have to find super string can be formed using these substrings or not
output should be "yes" or "no"

for example-

sub strings-
john 
mathew
carl

super String 1- johncarl (john and carl both are in sub strings)
ouput-yes

super String 2-carlmathewjohn(john,mathew and carl all are in sub strings)
output-yes

super String 3-mohammedjohn(no mohammed in substrings)
output-no

super String 4-johnadbul(no abdul in substrings)
output-no

super String 5-john
output yes

super String 6-carlmathewjohnrohit(no rohit in substrings)
output no

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? [ask]

Comment: how can we compare them,, 
read example because problem is hard to explain in words
simple substring finding  program  is easy 


but problem here is that comparison is not straight forward
1.there can be any number of substrings (john,carl,mathew.....n)
2.is formation of complete superstring possible by using one or more of those substrings and these substrings can be in any order(mathew-yes,mathewcarljohn-yes, carljohn- yes,john-yes,johncarl-yes) (carlmathewlevi-no, sunnymathew-no,moahmmedcarl-no, johncarlmathewmohammed-no, mohammed-no)
so i am not able find out how to compare

Comment: like superstring can be formed with just one substring or all substrings simultaneusly in any order but how can we compare that super string if formed from sub strings only or not

Comment: @UmeshPathak This is a dynamic programming problem with use of a HashMap. What have you tried code wise?

Comment: @vivek   i tried to take substring inputs in array as well as hash set but i am not getting how to compare superstring to sub strings can you tell me with some code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Map and typically a single pass.

Does the string start with any of the available words, if no, stop.

If yes, remove the word and continue until the string is consumed. or you have to stop. The only complexity is when here is multiple possible words to consume in which case you need to try them all. For this, you need recursion and some backtracking.